# Android + Pair devices via bluetooth programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to discover `bluetooth` devices in range, list and pair to them on click. I used following code but its just closing application when I click on device name which I want to pair.

I want to know mistake in my code or any other way to do what i need.

```
package com.marakana;

    import java.util.Set;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
    import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


    public class BluetoothDemo extends Activity {
    // Debugging
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    private static final boolean D = true;

    // Return Intent extra
    public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // Member fields
    private BluetoothAdapter mBtAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Setup the window
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.device_list);

        // Set result CANCELED incase the user backs out
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);

        // Initialize the button to perform device discovery
        Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
        scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                doDiscovery();
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        // Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and
        // one for newly discovered devices
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);
        mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.device_name);

        // Find and set up the ListView for paired devices
        ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
        pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices
        ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
        newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
        newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Get the local Bluetooth adapter
        mBtAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Get a set of currently paired devices
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBtAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
            mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
        if (mBtAdapter != null) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Unregister broadcast listeners
        this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    /**
     * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
     */
    private void doDiscovery() {
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "doDiscovery()");

        // Indicate scanning in the title
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        setTitle(R.string.scanning);

        // Turn on sub-title for new devices
        findViewById(R.id.title_new_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBtAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBtAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }

    // The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
    private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
            mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
            String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

            // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

            // Set result and finish this Activity
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    };

    // The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
    // changes the title when discovery is finished
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                setTitle(R.string.select_device);
                if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Please try to put your `BlueTooth Pairing Function` inside `some another Thread or AysncTask` as `Pairing` is irrevelant of time.

Comment: can you shed some light on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54529441/6880611)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In my first answer the logic is shown for those who want to go with the logic only.

I think I was not able to make clear to @chalukya3545, that's why I am adding the whole code to let him know the exact flow of the code.

**BluetoothDemo.java**

```
public class BluetoothDemo extends Activity {

    ListView listViewPaired;
    ListView listViewDetected;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    Button buttonSearch,buttonOn,buttonDesc,buttonOff;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,detectedAdapter;
    static HandleSeacrh handleSeacrh;
    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    BluetoothClass bdClass;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    private ButtonClicked clicked;
    ListItemClickedonPaired listItemClickedonPaired;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;

    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listViewDetected = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetected);
        listViewPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        buttonDesc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDesc);
        buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff); 
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        clicked = new ButtonClicked();
        handleSeacrh = new HandleSeacrh();
        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        /*
         * the above declaration is just for getting the paired bluetooth devices;
         * this helps in the removing the bond between paired devices.
         */
        listItemClickedonPaired = new ListItemClickedonPaired();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        listViewDetected.setAdapter(detectedAdapter);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();
        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonDesc.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        listViewDetected.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
        listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickedonPaired);
    }
    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();            
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
            {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    class ListItemClicked implements OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            //bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            Log.i("Log", "The dvice : "+bdDevice.toString());
            /*
             * here below we can do pairing without calling the callthread(), we can directly call the
             * connect(). but for the safer side we must usethe threading object.
             */
            //callThread();
            //connect(bdDevice);
            Boolean isBonded = false;
            try {
                isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                if(isBonded)
                {
                    //arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getPairedDevices();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }//connect(bdDevice);
            Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
        }       
    }
    class ListItemClickedonPaired implements OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
            bdDevice = arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            try {
                Boolean removeBonding = removeBond(bdDevice);
                if(removeBonding)
                {
                    arrayListpaired.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                Log.i("Log", "Removed"+removeBonding);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /*private void callThread() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Boolean isBonded = false;
                try {
                    isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                    if(isBonded)
                    {
                        arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }//connect(bdDevice);
                Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
            }           
        }.start();
    }*/
    private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice) { 
        Boolean bool = false;
        try {
            Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
            Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Class[] par = {};
            Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
            Object[] args = {};
            bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);//, args);// this invoke creates the detected devices paired.
            //Log.i("Log", "This is: "+bool.booleanValue());
            //Log.i("Log", "devicesss: "+bdDevice.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bool.booleanValue();
    };


    public boolean removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    {  
        Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }


    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }  


    class ButtonClicked implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonOn:
                onBluetooth();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSearch:
                arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                startSearching();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDesc:
                makeDiscoverable();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonOff:
                offBluetooth();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                try
                {
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", boolean.class).invoke(device);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Log", "Inside the exception: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if(arrayListBluetoothDevices.size()<1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                {                                           // device to the arraylist.
                    detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean flag = true;    // flag to indicate that particular device is already in the arlist or not
                    for(int i = 0; i<arrayListBluetoothDevices.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(device.getAddress().equals(arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(i).getAddress()))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag == true)
                    {
                        detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    };
    private void startSearching() {
        Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        BluetoothDemo.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
    private void onBluetooth() {
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            Log.i("Log", "Bluetooth is Enabled");
        }
    }
    private void offBluetooth() {
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }
    private void makeDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
    }
    class HandleSeacrh extends Handler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 111:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonOn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Make Discoverable"/>
   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Search"/>
   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/buttonOff"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Bluetooth Off"/>

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listViewPaired"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="120dp">

   </ListView>

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listViewDetected"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add this permissions to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />  
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

The output for this code will look like this.
[image: Bluutooth Demo]

Comment: @Narendra: Is it possible to use Android Device as Bluetooth handset?

Comment: if you got this working then you can upvote the answer.coz it will surely create the paired bond.

Comment: http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-programmatically-scan-or-discover-android-bluetooth-device/ i made a sample project to show how to enable/disable, discover ,pair and unpair bluetooth device.

Comment: @NarendraPal: in your code, specifically where did you pair the device? if so, did you use the key or something similar?, thanks for the code and further help.

Comment: @gus Check my another answer in the same thead which is with -1 downvote. There is a method "createBond" where I am calling the class1 method createBond and checking for the return boolean value. It will create bond and then return me TRUE if the bond is created else false.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use reflection to create the bond... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createBond() exists and it's public!

Comment: @Dadou because createBond() api added in API level 19, before that may be it's not present

Comment: @LorensiusW.L.T Your project doesn't compile as an Android project in Android Studio. How do you set it up?

Comment: can you shed some light on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54529441/6880611)

Comment: @TejasPandya my task was on just pairing with device and get something printed. not worked on bluetooth apart from that. I would love to hear from the developers on your question. upvoting your question for now. lets see how you get it sorted

Comment: Hi, is it possible to set auth PIN through code and disimiss that PIN pop up?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer 
please update the code based on this [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions)

Comment: When I move from one activity to another the device gets unpaired.

Answer (score 9):

**The Best way is do not use any pairing code**.
Instead of `onClick` go to other function or other class where You create the socket using UUID.
Android automatically pops up for pairing if already not paired.

or see this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660968/how-to-prevent-android-bluetooth-rfcomm-connection-from-dying-immediately-after) for better understanding

Below is code for the same:

```
private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
        mBtAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

        // Set result and finish this Activity
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

      // **add this 2 line code** 
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Connect.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        finish();
    }
};
```

Connect.java file is :

```
public class Connect extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "zeoconnect";
private ByteBuffer localByteBuffer;
 private InputStream in;
 byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[4096];
 int bytes;


  public BluetoothDevice mDevice;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connect);



              try {
                setup();
            } catch (ZeoMessageException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ZeoMessageParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }

 private void setup() throws ZeoMessageException, ZeoMessageParseException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                    new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                    new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));

            BluetoothDevice zee = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().
                    getRemoteDevice("**:**:**:**:**:**");// add device mac adress

            try {
                sock = zee.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(
                         UUID.fromString("*******************")); // use unique UUID
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "++++ Connecting");
            try {
                sock.connect();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "++++ Connected");


            try {
                in = sock.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

              Log.d(TAG, "++++ Listening...");

              while (true) {

                  try {
                      bytes = in.read(arrayOfByte);
                      Log.d(TAG, "++++ Read "+ bytes +" bytes");  
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                        Log.d(TAG, "++++ Done: test()"); 

                        }} 




 private static final LogBroadcastReceiver receiver = new LogBroadcastReceiver();
    public static class LogBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context paramAnonymousContext, Intent paramAnonymousIntent) {
            Log.d("ZeoReceiver", paramAnonymousIntent.toString());
            Bundle extras = paramAnonymousIntent.getExtras();
            for (String k : extras.keySet()) {
                Log.d("ZeoReceiver", "    Extra: "+ extras.get(k).toString());
            }
        }


    };

    private BluetoothSocket sock;
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        if (sock != null) {
            try {
                sock.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
 }
```

Comment: +1: _The Best way is do not use any pairing code._ Let Android manage pairing, up until now I haven't found any downside of not letting it to.

Comment: i've done it also this way. just open a socket and let android pair with the other device. keeps your app smaller ;) the popup opens automatically

Comment: not working in my case, getting "IOException bt socket closed, read return -1" for the line "bytes = in.read(arrayOfByte);" inside while loop and so activity not responding dialog with black screen when tested on Samsung SMT11 tab 4.4.2

Answer (score 6):

if you have the BluetoothDevice object you can create bond(pair) from api 19 onwards with `bluetoothDevice.createBond()` method.

**Edit**

for callback, if the request was accepted or denied you will have to create a BroadcastReceiver with `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED` action

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I have just explained logic to pair here. If anybody want to go with the complete code then see my another answer. I have answered here for logic only but I was not able to explain properly, So I have added another answer in the same thread.

Try this to do pairing:

If you are able to search the devices then this would be your next step

```
ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = NEW ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>;
```

I am assuming that you have the list of Bluetooth devices added in the `arrayListBluetoothDevices`:

```
BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(PASS_THE_POSITION_TO_GET_THE_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE);

Boolean isBonded = false;
try {
isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
if(isBonded)
{
    Log.i("Log","Paired");
}
} catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

The `createBond()` method:

```
public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }
```

**Add this line into your Receiver in the ACTION_FOUND**

```
if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                }
```

Comment: wat to specify for **position**

Comment: ya have created array list but again same this **(PASS_THE_POSITION_TO_GET_THE_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE)** part is showing error as PASS_THE_POSITION_TO_GET_THE_BLUETOOTH_DEVICE cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: have you created the ArrayList<BluetoothDevices>?? As I think after searching you are showing the list of bluetooth devices in the ListView. And after clicking on any searched device you would like to do pairing. M I RIGHT AT HERE???

Comment: ya same i'm able to list onclick nothing was happening...even tat part of code is present pal...

Comment: I have added a new answer,just checkout where you are going wrong.that is perfectly working code in my case. Goodluck

Comment: @NarendraPal I am facing problem in connection and the application crashes automatically..I spended more then a week in this problem

Comment: @Manish have you tried the solution said above? And at what stage you are getting this issue?

Comment: @NarendraPal I successfully find the bluetooth device. do you have any idea about bluetooth printing

Comment: I have done printing using some codes. was searching for print in diffrent font. I have written my code http://stackoverflow.com/q/12257164/1395259 for printing. you can check it. See if it can help you.