# How do I establish connection with obd2 from Android bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to establish connection with obd2 device from my Android app, like torque app. I need to pair it from Android phone.

Comment: please provide link to ur obd2 device so that it ll be more clear to which device is it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you in pairing with any bluetooth device

**BluetoothDemo.java**

```
package com.bluetooth;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.ParcelUuid;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class BluetoothDemo extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ListView listViewPaired;
    ListView listViewDetected;
    ArrayList<String> arrayListpaired;
    Button buttonSearch,buttonOn,buttonDesc,buttonOff;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter,detectedAdapter;
    static HandleSeacrh handleSeacrh;
    BluetoothDevice bdDevice;
    BluetoothClass bdClass;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices;
    private ButtonClicked clicked;
    ListItemClickedonPaired listItemClickedonPaired;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = null;
    ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> arrayListBluetoothDevices = null;
    ListItemClicked listItemClicked;
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        listViewDetected = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewDetected);
        listViewPaired = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewPaired);
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        buttonOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOn);
        buttonDesc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDesc);
        buttonOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOff); 
        arrayListpaired = new ArrayList<String>();
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        clicked = new ButtonClicked();
        handleSeacrh = new HandleSeacrh();
        arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        /*
         * the above declaration is just for getting the paired bluetooth devices;
         * this helps in the removing the bond between paired devices.
         */
        listItemClickedonPaired = new ListItemClickedonPaired();
        arrayListBluetoothDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListpaired);
        detectedAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(BluetoothDemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice);
        listViewDetected.setAdapter(detectedAdapter);
        listItemClicked = new ListItemClicked();
        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listViewPaired.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        getPairedDevices();
        buttonOn.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonSearch.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonDesc.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        buttonOff.setOnClickListener(clicked);
        listViewDetected.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClicked);
        listViewPaired.setOnItemClickListener(listItemClickedonPaired);
    }
    private void getPairedDevices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();            
        if(pairedDevice.size()>0)
        {
            for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevice)
            {
                arrayListpaired.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.add(device);
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    class ListItemClicked implements OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            bdDevice = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            //bdClass = arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            Log.i("Log", "The dvice : "+bdDevice.toString());
            /*
             * here below we can do pairing without calling the callthread(), we can directly call the
             * connect(). but for the safer side we must usethe threading object.
             */
            //callThread();
            //connect(bdDevice);
            Boolean isBonded = false;
            try {
                isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                if(isBonded)
                {
                    //arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    getPairedDevices();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }//connect(bdDevice);
            Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
        }       
    }
    class ListItemClickedonPaired implements OnItemClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
            bdDevice = arrayListPairedBluetoothDevices.get(position);
            try {
                Boolean removeBonding = removeBond(bdDevice);
                if(removeBonding)
                {
                    arrayListpaired.remove(position);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                

                Log.i("Log", "Removed"+removeBonding);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /*private void callThread() {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                Boolean isBonded = false;
                try {
                    isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
                    if(isBonded)
                    {
                        arrayListpaired.add(bdDevice.getName()+"\n"+bdDevice.getAddress());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }//connect(bdDevice);
                Log.i("Log", "The bond is created: "+isBonded);
            }           
        }.start();
    }*/
    private Boolean connect(BluetoothDevice bdDevice) { 
        Boolean bool = false;
        try {
            Log.i("Log", "service method is called ");
            Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
            Class[] par = {};
            Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
            Object[] args = {};
            bool = (Boolean) method.invoke(bdDevice);//, args);// this invoke creates the detected devices paired.
            //Log.i("Log", "This is: "+bool.booleanValue());
            //Log.i("Log", "devicesss: "+bdDevice.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Log", "Inside catch of serviceFromDevice Method");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bool.booleanValue();
    };


    public boolean removeBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    {  
        Class btClass = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method removeBondMethod = btClass.getMethod("removeBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) removeBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }


    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }  


    class ButtonClicked implements OnClickListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.buttonOn:
                onBluetooth();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonSearch:
                arrayListBluetoothDevices.clear();
                startSearching();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonDesc:
                makeDiscoverable();
                break;
            case R.id.buttonOff:
                offBluetooth();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_FOUND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                try
                {
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
                    //device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput", boolean.class).invoke(device);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("Log", "Inside the exception: ");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                if(arrayListBluetoothDevices.size()<1) // this checks if the size of bluetooth device is 0,then add the
                {                                           // device to the arraylist.
                    detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                    arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                    detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    boolean flag = true;    // flag to indicate that particular device is already in the arlist or not
                    for(int i = 0; i<arrayListBluetoothDevices.size();i++)
                    {
                        if(device.getAddress().equals(arrayListBluetoothDevices.get(i).getAddress()))
                        {
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(flag == true)
                    {
                        detectedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());
                        arrayListBluetoothDevices.add(device);
                        detectedAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            }           
        }
    };
    private void startSearching() {
        Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        BluetoothDemo.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
    private void onBluetooth() {
        if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.enable();
            Log.i("Log", "Bluetooth is Enabled");
        }
    }
    private void offBluetooth() {
        if(bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            bluetoothAdapter.disable();
        }
    }
    private void makeDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
    }
    class HandleSeacrh extends Handler
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case 111:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the **main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonOn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On"/>
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/buttonDesc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Make Discoverable"/>
   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Search"/>
   <Button 
       android:id="@+id/buttonOff"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Bluetooth Off"/>
   
   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listViewPaired"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="120dp">
       
   </ListView>

   <ListView 
       android:id="@+id/listViewDetected"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       
   </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Add this permissions to your menifest file.**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

It helped me in same case.. answered by [Narendra pal here on my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14254202/1752560)

Comment: @raja: Did this work for you? Here is the link of the device I am aiming for. 
http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B005NLQAHS/ref=oh_details_o01_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: hi can anybody tell me how to communicate with OBD II to android over wifi?

Answer (score 3):

> This service is used to find paired OBD-2, connect and keep fetching real time data i.e standard PIDs and find other real time parameter based on standard PIDs, like total travelled distance, fuel consumption, etc in background. This is tested in Mobile and Head Unit (installed in Car). Refer android-obd-reader sample app:

https://github.com/md-sohrab-alam/android-obd-reader

```
package com.sohrab.obd.reader.service;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.sohrab.obd.reader.application.ObdPreferences;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.constants.DefineObdReader;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.enums.ObdProtocols;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.ObdCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.ObdConfiguration;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.control.TroubleCodesCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.protocol.EchoOffCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.protocol.LineFeedOffCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.protocol.ObdResetCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.protocol.SelectProtocolCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.protocol.SpacesOffCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.obdCommand.protocol.TimeoutCommand;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.trip.TripRecord;
import com.sohrab.obd.reader.utils.L;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import app.com.android_obd_reader.R;


/**
 * created by sohrab 01/12/2017
 * <p>
 * Service for managing connection and data communication with a OBD-2 in background and update data to RealTime screen.
 * It connects paired OBD-2 Or wait until paired.
 * Once it is paired, try to connect with Bluetooth Socket along with some specific OBD-2 command,
 * if connected, fetch data until OBD-2 disconnected and if somehow,
 * it disconnected then go to connect and this is in loop until user quit from App.
 */

public class ObdReaderService extends IntentService implements DefineObdReader {
    private static final String TAG = "ObdReaderService";
    // receive when OBD-2 connected


    public final static char PID_STATUS_SUCCESS = '1';
    public final static int DEVICE_NOT_PAIRED = 1;
    public final static int OBD_NOT_RESPONDING = 2;
    public final static int OBD_CONNECTED = 3;
    public final static int INIT_OBD = 4;


    //   private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;
    private static final int DELAY_FIFTEEN_SECOND = 15000;
    private static final int DELAY_TWO_SECOND = 2000;
    // this is used to find TroubleCode if true. This is used in InspectionActivity where fault is shown.
    public boolean mIsFaultCodeRead = true;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    //   private int mLastNotificationType;
    // name of OBD
    private String OBD_SMALL = "obd";
    private String OBD_CAPS = "OBD";
    private String V_LINK = "V-LINK";
    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;//Bluetooth Manager
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;//Bluetooth adapter
    private BluetoothSocket mSocket;
    //set OBD-2 connection status
    private boolean isConnected;
    // private NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder;
    //  private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private boolean mIsRunningSuccess;
    private Intent mIntent = new Intent(ACTION_READ_OBD_REAL_TIME_DATA);
    private char[] mSupportedPids;

    public ObdReaderService() {
        super("ObdReaderService");
        L.i("ObdReaderService");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        L.i("onHandleIntent" + "Thread is :: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

        // setUpAsForeground();
        if (initiateConnection()) {

            if (!isEnable()) {
                enableBlutooth();
            }

            findObdDevicesAndConnect();
        }

        L.i("onHandleIntent bottom");
        //  mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setServiceRunningStatus(false);
        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setIsOBDconnected(false);
        TripRecord.getTripRecode(this).clear();
    }

    /**
     * This method is recursively called until service stopped.
     */
    private void findObdDevicesAndConnect() {

        if (!isConnected) {
            findPairedDevices();
        }

        if (isConnected) {
            executeCommand();
        }

        if (ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).getServiceRunningStatus()) {
            L.i("findObdDevicesAndConnect()");
            findObdDevicesAndConnect();
        }

    }

    /**
     * find paired OBD-2 devices in loop until found and connected or service stopped.
     */
    private void findPairedDevices() {

        while (!isConnected && ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).getServiceRunningStatus()) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
                boolean deviceFound = false;

                Set<BluetoothDevice> bluetoothDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                for (BluetoothDevice device : bluetoothDevices) {
                    if (device != null) {
                        String name = device.getName();
                        if (name != null && (name.contains(OBD_SMALL) || name.contains(OBD_CAPS) || name.toUpperCase().contains(V_LINK))) {
                            try {
                                connectOBDDevice(device);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                L.i("connectOBDDevice return Exception :: " + e != null ? e.getMessage() : "");
                            }
                            deviceFound = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (!deviceFound) {
                  /*  if (mLastNotificationType != DEVICE_NOT_PAIRED) {
                        mLastNotificationType = DEVICE_NOT_PAIRED;
                        updateNotification(getString(R.string.waiting_for_obd));
                    }*/
                    sendBroadcast(ACTION_OBD_CONNECTION_STATUS, getString(R.string.waiting_for_obd));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * connects specified bluetooth OBD device with Bluetooth Socket.
     * if bluetooth socked connected then use some init OBD-2 command to initialize,
     * if command response is success, then we assume connection is established and ready to fetch data.
     *
     * @param device
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void connectOBDDevice(final BluetoothDevice device) throws Exception {

        try {
            mSocket = (BluetoothSocket) device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[]{int.class}).invoke(device, 1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            L.i("createInsecureRfcommSocket failed");
            closeSocket();
        }

        if (mSocket != null) {
            try {
                mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                Thread.sleep(500);
                mSocket.connect();
                L.i("Socket connected");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                L.i("Socket connection  exception :: " + e.getMessage());
                //   e.printStackTrace();
                closeSocket();
            }

            boolean isSockedConnected = mSocket.isConnected();
            if (isSockedConnected) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY_TWO_SECOND);
                  /*  if (mLastNotificationType != INIT_OBD) {
                        mLastNotificationType = INIT_OBD;
                        updateNotification(getString(R.string.connecting_to_ecu));
                    }*/
                    L.i("Executing reset command in new Thread :: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    final Thread newThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {

                                // this thread is required because in Headunit command.run method block infinitly ,
                                // therefore this thread life is maximum 15 second so that block can be handled.
                                mIsRunningSuccess = false;
                                new ObdResetCommand().run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                new EchoOffCommand().run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                                new LineFeedOffCommand().run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                                new SpacesOffCommand().run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                                new SpacesOffCommand().run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                                new TimeoutCommand(125).run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                //  updateNotification(getString(R.string.searching_protocol));
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                                new SelectProtocolCommand(ObdProtocols.AUTO).run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                                new EchoOffCommand().run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                                //  updateNotification(getString(R.string.searching_supported_sensor));
                                Thread.sleep(200);
                                mIsRunningSuccess = true;
                                // checkPid0To20(true);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                mIsRunningSuccess = false;
                                L.i("In new thread reset command  exception :: " + e != null ? e.getMessage() : "");
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    newThread.start();
                    newThread.join(DELAY_FIFTEEN_SECOND);
                    L.i("Thread wake to check reset command status  i.e  :: " + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ",  mIsRunningSuccess :: " + mIsRunningSuccess);
                    isSockedConnected = mIsRunningSuccess;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    L.i(" reset command Exception  :: " + e.getMessage());
                    isSockedConnected = false;
                }

            }

            if (mSocket != null && mSocket.isConnected() && isSockedConnected) {
                setConnection(false);
               /* if (mLastNotificationType != OBD_CONNECTED) {
                    mLastNotificationType = OBD_CONNECTED;
                    updateNotification(getString(R.string.connected_ok));
                }
*/
            } else {
                if (mSupportedPids != null && mSupportedPids.length == 32) {

                    if ((mSupportedPids[12] != PID_STATUS_SUCCESS) || (mSupportedPids[11] != PID_STATUS_SUCCESS)) {
                        // speed pid not supportedsupported
                        // updateNotification(getString(R.string.unable_to_connect));
                        sendBroadcast(ACTION_OBD_CONNECTION_STATUS, getString(R.string.unable_to_connect));
                        return;
                    }
                }

                sendBroadcast(ACTION_OBD_CONNECTION_STATUS, getString(R.string.obd2_adapter_not_responding));
/*
                if (mLastNotificationType != OBD_NOT_RESPONDING) {
                    mLastNotificationType = OBD_NOT_RESPONDING;
                    updateNotification(getString(R.string.obd2_adapter_not_responding));
                }
*/
            }
        }

    }


    /**
     * Once OBD-2 connected, this method will execute to fetch data continuously until OBD disconnected or Service stopped.
     */
    private void executeCommand() {
        L.i("executing commands thread is :: " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        TripRecord tripRecord = TripRecord.getTripRecode(this);
        ArrayList<ObdCommand> commands = (ArrayList<ObdCommand>) ObdConfiguration.getmObdCommands().clone();
        int count = 0;
        while (mSocket != null && mSocket.isConnected() && commands.size() > count && isConnected && ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).getServiceRunningStatus()) {

            ObdCommand command = commands.get(count);
            try {

                L.i("command run :: " + command.getName());
                command.run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                L.i("result is :: " + command.getFormattedResult() + " :: name is :: " + command.getName());
                tripRecord.updateTrip(command.getName(), command);
                if (mIsFaultCodeRead) {
                    try {
                        TroubleCodesCommand troubleCodesCommand = new TroubleCodesCommand();
                        troubleCodesCommand.run(mSocket.getInputStream(), mSocket.getOutputStream());
                        tripRecord.updateTrip(troubleCodesCommand.getName(), troubleCodesCommand);
                        mIsFaultCodeRead = false;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (mIntent == null)
                    mIntent = new Intent(ACTION_READ_OBD_REAL_TIME_DATA);
                sendBroadcast(mIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                L.i("execute command Exception  :: " + e.getMessage());

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(e.getMessage()) && (e.getMessage().equals("Broken pipe") || e.getMessage().equals("Connection reset by peer"))) {
                    L.i("command Exception  :: " + e.getMessage());
                    setDisconnection();
/*
                    if (mLastNotificationType != OBD_NOT_RESPONDING) {
                        mLastNotificationType = OBD_NOT_RESPONDING;
                        updateNotification(getString(R.string.obd2_adapter_not_responding));
                    }
*/
                }
            }
            count++;
            if (count == commands.size()) {
                count = 0;
            }

        }

        // exit loop means connection lost, so set connection status false
        isConnected = false;

    }

    /**
     * send broadcast with specific action and data
     *
     * @param action
     * @param data
     */
    private void sendBroadcast(final String action, String data) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.putExtra(ObdReaderService.INTENT_OBD_EXTRA_DATA, data);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    /**
     * send broadcast with specific action
     *
     * @param action
     */
    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        //fetchLocation();
        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setServiceRunningStatus(true);
        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setIsOBDconnected(false);
        //   mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        L.i("Service Created :: ");
    }


    /**
     * check whether this devices support bluetooth
     *
     * @return
     */
    protected boolean initiateConnection() {
        boolean isBlueToothSupported = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
        boolean isInitialized = initialize();

        if (!isBlueToothSupported || !isInitialized) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.bluetooth_unsupported), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * check BluetoothServices available in this device or not
     *
     * @return
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {

                return false;
            }
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        } else {
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        }
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        L.i("service onDestroy");
        //mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
        closeSocket();
        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setServiceRunningStatus(false);
        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setIsOBDconnected(false);
        TripRecord.getTripRecode(this).clear();
    }

    /**
     * close Bluetooth Socket
     */
    private void closeSocket() {
        L.i("socket closed :: ");
        if (mSocket != null) {
            try {
                mSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                L.i("socket closing failed :: ");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * check whether Bluetooth is enable or not
     *
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isEnable() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null)
            return false;
        return mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();

    }

    /**
     * enable bluetooth without user interaction
     *
     * @return
     */
    public boolean enableBlutooth() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null)
            return mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean stopService(Intent name) {
        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setServiceRunningStatus(false);
        return super.stopService(name);

    }

    /*Method used to set device disconnected state through the application...*/
    public void setDisconnection() {
/*
        if (mLastNotificationType != OBD_NOT_RESPONDING) {
            mLastNotificationType = OBD_NOT_RESPONDING;
            updateNotification(getString(R.string.obd2_adapter_not_responding));
        }
*/

        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setIsOBDconnected(false);
        isConnected = false;
        closeSocket();
        L.i("socket disconnected :: ");
      //  broadcastUpdate(ACTION_OBD_DISCONNECTED);
        sendBroadcast(ACTION_OBD_CONNECTION_STATUS, getString(R.string.connect_lost));
    }

    /*Method used to set device connected state through the application...*/
    private void setConnection(boolean isFromBle) {

        ObdPreferences.get(getApplicationContext()).setIsOBDconnected(true);
        isConnected = true;
       // sendBroadcast(ACTION_OBD_CONNECTED, String.valueOf(isFromBle));
        sendBroadcast(ACTION_OBD_CONNECTION_STATUS, getString(R.string.obd_connected));
    }

    /**
     * create Binder instance used to return in onBind method
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ObdReaderService getService() {
            return ObdReaderService.this;
        }
    }




}
```