# How to implement an app using OBD2 (ELM327) like Torque in android?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, obd-ii, elm327

I am very new to obd2 and elm327. I need to develop an application to get car info using obd2(bluetooth) and elm327. Please any one can help.

Comment: Refer android-obd-reader sample app:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706779

Comment: Hi @Latha, have you got solution ?

Answer (score 12):

As I maintain a bluetooth OBD Android application, I'll give you some directions.

Start with the [Bluetooth Chat](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/BluetoothChat) sample application to learn the basics of communicating with a bluetooth serial device. Then study the [ELM327 Programmers Guide](http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf) to learn the specifics of the protocol. Checkout [existing projects](https://github.com/fr3ts0n/AndrOBD) for ideas.

Comment: existing projects , which contains swings and awt , but those are not supported by android? is that a good example for beginner ?

Comment: This is a fair criticism. [Here's some more projects to look through on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=elm327+OR+stn1110+OR+obd+AND+android&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults) I've included projects that mention the [ST1110](https://www.scantool.net/scantool/downloads/102/stn1110_vs_elm327.pdf) as it is a much better chip that is compatible with the ELM327 command set. But still, I'd really encourage you to learn and fully understand the bluetooth chat app, as a beginner to android you'll need to learn to implement services for things like bluetooth communication.

Comment: Thank you for your encouragement. i understood blue tooth chat app functionality like scanning for devices , how it connecting and hoe it retrieving and sending messages in it, but now i need help to understand how to work with obd elm327 in android .

Answer (score 4):

I want to suggest [android-obd-reader](https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader) (Android OBD-II Reader application that uses pure OBD-II PID's Java API.) example which helps you to get more idea about developing app using OBD-II.

See [OBD-II Java API](https://github.com/pires/obd-java-api) which also help you.

Comment: The project is deprecated and does not work anymore. It was also archived on github.

Comment: this project is deprecated. May I know , Any possibility to read the from OBD2 simulator in android application through Bluetooth ?