# Android Connect Bluetooth device automatically after pairing programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth

In my app I need pairing bluetooth device and immediately connect with it.

I have the following function in order to pairing devices:

```
public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)
{
    try {
        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Start Pairing...");
        Method m = btDevice.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) m.invoke(btDevice, (Object[]) null);
        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Pairing finished.");
        return returnValue;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("pairDevice()", e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

And I use it as the following way:

```
Boolean isBonded = false;
try {
    isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
    if(isBonded)
    {
         //Connect with device
    }
}
```

And it show me the dialog to pairing devices and enter the pin.

The problem is that createBond functions always return true, and it doen's wait until I enter the pin and paired with device, so I don't use correctly:

```
isBonded = createBond(bdDevice);
if(isBonded) {...}
```

So the question is How can I paired with device and when it is paired connect to it?

P.D My code is based in the first answer of the following thread: [Android + Pair devices via bluetooth programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228289/android-device-bluetooth-pairing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

First I need a `BroadcastReceiver` like:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                // CONNECT
            }
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Discover new device
        }
    }
};
```

And then I need register the receiver as follow:

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
context.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
```

In this way the receiver is listening for `ACTION_FOUND` (Discover new device) and `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED` (Device change its bond state), then I check if the new state is `BOND_BOUNDED` and if it is I connect with device.

Now when I call `createBond` Method (described in the question) and enter the pin, `ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED` will fire and `device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED` will be `True` and it will connect.

Comment: What methods did you use to programmatically connect the bluetooth device? I understand how to programmatically pair, but it's difficult to connect in a broadcast receiver.

Comment: for a SPP conection I use the following lines: ``BluetoothDevice device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(mac);`` ``final UUID SERIAL_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");`` ``socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);`` ``socket.connect();`` ``out = socket.getOutputStream();`` ``in = socket.getInputStream();`` Where ``adapter`` is an instance of ``BluetoothAdapter`` and ``mac`` is a String.

Comment: why not directly to use mmSocket.connect() in order to connect and communicate with another device?

Comment: First, I need to create Socket object, I use line 1,2 and 3 to create socket object and then I use `socket.connect();`