# Android/Bluetooth programmatically pairing options

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing

I have a list of BluetoothDevice and I want to pair programmatically with one of them that has a PIN.
I have read several posts here in which the subject is discussed, but I've found two very different approachs.

**FIRST OPTION:** You call the `device.createBond()` method. Then, on a BroadcastReceiver, you listen the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST` action and there you call 
`device.setPin(PIN_BYTES);
device.setPinConfirmation(true);`

You can see the complete example & post here: [How to pair Bluetooth device programmatically Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168263/how-to-pair-bluetooth-device-programmatically-android)

**SECOND OPTION:** What if you call `device.setPin(PIN_BYTES)` and `device.setPinConfirmation(true)` first, and then `device.createBond()`? Eg:

```
if(connConfig!=null && connConfig.bluetooth!=null){
    device.setPin(connConfig.bluetooth.pass);
    device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
    device.createBond();
}
```

And then you forget about listening the `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST` action on your BroadcastReceiver and only pay attention to `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED` events? [Android + Pair devices via bluetooth programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228289/android-pair-devices-via-bluetooth-programmatically)
See in the first answer the code. As far as I get it, that dude isn't using any PIN for pairing, so I also need to use the setPin method.

Which of both you find better?
Am I missing something? BTW: I'm not using reflection because Im not targeting older platforms.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The only real questions I can see are *"Which of both you find better?"* and *"Am I missing something?"* which are asking for opinions and that is off-topic. Please [edit] your question to make it clearer. Please also read the [help] pages about how to write a good question and about what sort of questions are allowed.

Comment: @gabdev Did you find a sensible solution to your question?  I am wondering the same right now.