# Pair a bluetooth device in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm creating an app that should connect via bluetooth to a specific device.

I want my app to connect with this device no matter it is already paired or not.

For now I have this

```
private void findDevice() {
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if (device.getName().equals(DEVICE_NAME)) {
                bluetoothDevice = device;
                deviceFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this function connects only to paired devices.
If my device isn't already paired, I want to pair it.
Have no idea how to do this.

Can someone get me any advice please?

Comment: Did you request BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission?

Comment: yes, I did request

Comment: Did you try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228289/android-pair-devices-via-bluetooth-programmatically

Comment: To be honest i have a problem with understanding the code from that topic.
Im totaly new to Android studio.

Comment: im using 
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();  

to get all already bonded Devices, then just compare theirs names to find the one im willing to connect to.

But haveing a problem with creating same list for unbonded devices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First request `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission.

Then make your device discoverable:

```
private void makeDiscoverable() {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
        Log.i("Log", "Discoverable ");
    }
```

Then create a **BroadcastReceiver** to listen to action from system:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
               //Found, add to a device list
            }           
        }
    };
```

And start searching for devices by registering this **BoardcastReceiver**:

```
 private void startSearching() {
        Log.i("Log", "in the start searching method");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        BluetoothDemo.this.registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    }
```

After devices come from the **BroadcastReceiver** into a list, select your device from the list and `createBond()` with this:

```
 public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice btDevice)  
    throws Exception  
    { 
        Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
        Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");  
        Boolean returnValue = (Boolean) createBondMethod.invoke(btDevice);  
        return returnValue.booleanValue();  
    }
```

Then use your code above to manage with bonded devices.

Comment: man, much thanks, seems legit.
But having a problem with BroadcastReciever.
Android Studio says i cannot resolve a symbol 'BroadcastReciever'.

Im searching on google for answer but cant find one :(

Comment: @Kirchhoff1415 what problem?

Comment: ok, got it, i was missing
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
part

Comment: So did you suceed?

Comment: ok, im having a problem with "created bond" function.

im getting Cannot resolve symbol with 'Method' and with 'invoke'

i've already coppied all imports from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228289/android-pair-devices-via-bluetooth-programmatically

but it didnt help :(

Comment: This may help `import java.lang.reflect.Method;` @Kirchhoff1415

Comment: @Kirchhoff1415 Good to hear that, if it work please mark my answer accepted for others to read.

Comment: @Kharisma `BluetoothDemo` is your activity. See [Context#registerReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%2520android.content.IntentFilter))

Comment: where can I got this `bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();`