# Obtaining a List of Available Bluetooth Devices on Android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841534/pair-a-bluetooth-device-in-android-studio), @nhoxbypass provides this method for the purpose of adding found Bluetooth devices to a list:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
               //Found, add to a device list
            }           
        }
    };
```

However, I do not understand how a reference to the found device can be obtained, how can this be done?

I do not have permission to comment on the original question, so I have chosen to extend it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Bluetooth guide in the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) explains this:

> In order to receive information about each device discovered, your application must register a BroadcastReceiver for the ACTION_FOUND intent. The system broadcasts this intent for each device. The intent contains the extra fields EXTRA_DEVICE and EXTRA_CLASS, which in turn contain a BluetoothDevice and a BluetoothClass, respectively.

This sample code is included as well:

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     ...
>
>     // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
>     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
>     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
> }
>
> // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
> private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
>         String action = intent.getAction();
>         if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
>             // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
>             // object and its info from the Intent.
>             BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
>             String deviceName = device.getName();
>             String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
>         }
>     }
> };
> ```

If you are working with Bluetooth on Android, I suggest to read that guide carefully. Then read it one more time ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much, I shall follow your advice ;)

Comment: on `intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)` I got null value. Am I missing someting? I already add `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` , `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` , `BLUETOOTH` , and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission to AndroidManifest and make sure `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` grandted

Answer (score 2):

From the [`ACTION_FOUND` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_FOUND):

> Always contains the extra fields `EXTRA_DEVICE` and `EXTRA_CLASS`. Can contain the extra fields `EXTRA_NAME` and/or `EXTRA_RSSI` if they are available.

[`EXTRA_DEVICE` can be used to obtain the `BluetoothDevice` that was found](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#EXTRA_DEVICE) via code like:

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
```

Comment: So to clarify, `BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE` would the found device of type `BluetoothDevice`?