# Bluetooth "Additional settings" in Xiaomi Redmi Note8 Pro or above

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, redmi-device

I wrote the code to turn ON and scan the available Bluetooth.

[Reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228289/android-pair-devices-via-bluetooth-programmatically)

[Reference2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806536/how-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-programmatically-in-android)

The code works fine on all the phones except "Xiaomi Redmi Note8 Pro" or above.

The Redmi phone has Additional settings under Bluetooth settings.

1. **Pair compatible devices**
2. **Show Bluetooth devices without names.**

Basically, I am trying to pair Bluetooth devices having No Name with this phone.
But not able to enable this setting through the code.
I manually need to enable this setting then only devices able to connect with this phone.

How to enable all the Bluetooth settings in Redmi phones??

Find the screenshots.

[image: Bluetooth Settings]
[image: Additional Settings]
[image: OS Version]

Comment: As you mentioned, that you have written the code to scan,  is the device with No name present in the scan list ?

Comment: It scans the device with no name only when the second setting "Show Bluetooth devices without names." is enabled.
If this setting is disabled then it scans the device with the name only.
And I am not able to find the code to enable this setting.