# How to develop Java desktop application to connect with bluetooth "HC-05"?

Tags: java, bluetooth, communication

I want to develop Java desktop application, to connect my PC with bluetooth "HC-05". I have studied Java in my college, and that's my first application. so I hope more details as could as possible, specially in establishing the connection between PC and HC-05 (with easy Tutorials and Resources, if possible).

And is it possible to transmit data in form of **Array** using this application?, or it is better to transmit **Integers**?

Comment: See this post for more information: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675208/to-discover-and-pair-bluetooth-devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675208/to-discover-and-pair-bluetooth-devices)

Answer (score 2):

Also this site has a lot of information about your problem:

[Connecting to Bluetooth devices with Java](http://www.aviyehuda.com/blog/2010/01/08/connecting-to-bluetooth-devices-with-java/)